# MYSQL MULTI JOINS with COUNTS

Tags: mysql, join, count

Base data model: https://i.stack.imgur.com/83pzq.jpg

Hi, thx for the help!

I want to make a query to get the number(count) of problems and the number of answers from a course,

```
SELECT 
courses.name,
courses.description,
courses.digest,
courses.views,
categories.icon,
COUNT(answers.id),
COUNT(problems.id) 
FROM
   courses
        INNER JOIN
    topics ON topics.id = courses.topics_id
       INNER JOIN
   categories ON categories.id = topics.categories_id
       LEFT JOIN
   problems ON problems.courses_id = courses.id
       LEFT JOIN
   answers ON answers.problems_id = problems_id
WHERE
   courses.accounts_id = 1
GROUP BY courses.id
```

But this is not working any ideas?

thx

Comment: Is the error message or unexpected behaviour classified? If not, pls share it with us.

Comment: May be a typo but on your last join you're doing `answers.problems_id = problems_id` is this correct? Should it be problems.id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be a typo but on your last join you're doing

`answers.problems_id = problems_id`

And you have no `problems_id` columns in your problems table or any other table except answers table.

Should it be `problems.id`?

Comment: Thx! i changed it to problems.id but i still making a new query to coun the answers.